# Configuring Kubernetes DNS nameservers

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, dns

I have a pod that cannot resolve the IP address for a domain. The DNS entry is setup on a Windows AD network and the *node* uses these windows servers for DNS and *can* correctly resolve the IP.

However, when I run a pod, it picks up a K8S DNS server (e.g. 10.43.0.10) which somehow does not use the parent node's DNS servers but is only using external ones so it can resolve e.g. google.com but not my internal DNS. The only complication is that there is an external SOA record for the domain (with public DNS entries) but this should not be used if only the AD servers are queried.

There are so many documents that talk about DNS for the cluster itself but I cannot work out how the cluster configures DNS for resolving external domains.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually, I found out that the issue was not with Kubernetes configuration but with the DNS configuration on the Ubuntu nodes. Systemd-resolve is pretty complicated and the way I had added the custom nameservers against the interface meant that they worked on the node but were not found by the core-dns pods.

I then realised that due to some limitations of systemd-resolve and the max number of nameservers, it was easier instead to install dnsmasq in place of systemd with a much simpler resolv.conf and then I got it to work as expected.